# access the weight attribute in code

Tags: android

I have the following code within my layout xml file

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentTextViewLayout"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I fetch the value of layout_weight attribute of the RelativeLayout in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Why not instead just get the width of the relative layout, then set the width of the edittext to a percentage of the layout width.

```
int i = relativelayout.getWidth();
int x = //any number, depending on how wide you what your text view
textview.setWidth(i/x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Try the following :

```
RelativeLayout r = ((RelativeLayout)(findViewById(R.id.contentTextViewLayout))); 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.weight = 1.0f;
r.setLayoutParams(params);
```

params.weight = 1.0f can be changed as per your desire.